# Не работает обратная связь

Tags: php, javascript, html, хостинг

Не могу понять, почему не работает обратная связь.

В логах пишет ошибку:

```
[31-Mar-2018 17:09:27 Asia/Tashkent] PHP Warning:  mail() has been disabled for security reasons in /home/metallce/public_html/script/mail.php on line 52
```

**HTML:**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>uniMail</title>
</head>
<body>

    <form>

        <!-- Hidden Required Fields -->
        <input type="hidden" name="project_name" value="MetallCenter.uz">
        <input type="hidden" name="admin_email" value="feedback@metallcenter.uz">
        <input type="hidden" name="form_subject" value="FeedBack - mc.uz">
        <!-- END Hidden Required Fields -->

        <input type="text" name="Name" placeholder="You name..." required><br>
        <input type="text" name="E-mail" placeholder="You E-mail..." required><br>
        <input type="text" name="Phone" placeholder="You phone..."><br>
        <button>Send</button>

    </form>

    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.3.min.js"></script>
    <script src="script.js"></script>

</body>
</html>
```

**JavaScript**

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    //E-mail Ajax Send
    $("form").submit(function() { //Change
        var th = $(this);
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "mail.php", //Change
            data: th.serialize()
        }).done(function() {
            alert("Thank you!");
            setTimeout(function() {
                // Done Functions
                th.trigger("reset");
            }, 1000);
        });
        return false;
    });

});
```

**PHP**

```
<?php

$method = $_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'];

//Script Foreach
$c = true;
if ( $method === 'POST' ) {

    $project_name = trim($_POST["project_name"]);
    $admin_email  = trim($_POST["admin_email"]);
    $form_subject = trim($_POST["form_subject"]);

    foreach ( $_POST as $key => $value ) {
        if ( $value != "" && $key != "project_name" && $key != "admin_email" && $key != "form_subject" ) {
            $message .= "
            " . ( ($c = !$c) ? '<tr>':'<tr style="background-color: #f8f8f8;">' ) . "
                <td style='padding: 10px; border: #e9e9e9 1px solid;'><b>$key</b></td>
                <td style='padding: 10px; border: #e9e9e9 1px solid;'>$value</td>
            </tr>
            ";
        }
    }
} else if ( $method === 'GET' ) {

    $project_name = trim($_GET["project_name"]);
    $admin_email  = trim($_GET["admin_email"]);
    $form_subject = trim($_GET["form_subject"]);

    foreach ( $_GET as $key => $value ) {
        if ( $value != "" && $key != "project_name" && $key != "admin_email" && $key != "form_subject" ) {
            $message .= "
            " . ( ($c = !$c) ? '<tr>':'<tr style="background-color: #f8f8f8;">' ) . "
                <td style='padding: 10px; border: #e9e9e9 1px solid;'><b>$key</b></td>
                <td style='padding: 10px; border: #e9e9e9 1px solid;'>$value</td>
            </tr>
            ";
        }
    }
}

$message = "<table style='width: 100%;'>$message</table>";

function adopt($text) {
    return '=?UTF-8?B?'.Base64_encode($text).'?=';
}

$headers = "MIME-Version: 1.0" . PHP_EOL .
"Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8" . PHP_EOL .
'From: '.adopt($project_name).' <'.$admin_email.'>' . PHP_EOL .
'Reply-To: '.$admin_email.'' . PHP_EOL;

mail($admin_email, adopt($form_subject), $message, $headers );
```

Comment: Саппорт хостинга спрашивайте.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Воспользовался phpmiler, настроил на свой хост, указав логин и пароль от хоста.

```
<?php
// Файлы phpmailer
require 'class.phpmailer.php';
require 'class.smtp.php';

$name = $_POST['name'];
$email = $_POST['email'];
$message = $_POST['message'];

// Настройки
$mail = new PHPMailer;

$mail->isSMTP(); 
$mail->Host = '-'; // адрес вашего хоста, mail.мой сайт.ru
$mail->SMTPAuth = true;                      
$mail->Username = '-'; // Ваш логин от хостинга или почты
$mail->Password = '-'; // Ваш пароль
$mail->SMTPSecure = 'ssl';                            
$mail->Port = 465;
$mail->setFrom('-'); // Ваш Email- можн такой же как у получателя.
$mail->addAddress('-'); // Email получателя

// Прикрепление файлов
  for ($ct = 0; $ct < count($_FILES['userfile']['tmp_name']); $ct++) {
        $uploadfile = tempnam(sys_get_temp_dir(), sha1($_FILES['userfile']['name'][$ct]));
        $filename = $_FILES['userfile']['name'][$ct];
        if (move_uploaded_file($_FILES['userfile']['tmp_name'][$ct], $uploadfile)) {
            $mail->addAttachment($uploadfile, $filename);
        } else {
            $msg .= 'Failed to move file to ' . $uploadfile;
        }
    }   

// Письмо
$mail->isHTML(true); 
$mail->Subject = "-"; // Заголовок письма
$mail->Body    = "Имя $name . Сообщение $message . Почта $email"; // Текст письма

// Результат
if(!$mail->send()) {
    echo 'Message could not be sent.';
    echo 'Mailer Error: ' . $mail->ErrorInfo;
} else {
    echo 'ok';
}
?>
```

---

```
$(function(){
  'use strict';
$('#form').on('submit', function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    var fd = new FormData( this );
    $.ajax({
      url: '../php/send.php',
      type: 'POST',
      contentType: false, 
      processData: false, 
      data: fd,
    }).done(function() {
      alert("Спасибо! Сообщение доставленно.");
      setTimeout(function() {
        form.reset();
        th.trigger("reset");
      }, 1000);
    });
  });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Добрый день.
В ошибке ясно сказано, что функция mail() отключена в целях безопасности.
**PHP Warning:  mail() has been disabled for security reasons**

Обращайтесь в службу поддержки или используйте иной вариант для отправки сообщений.